# how to switch windows between cpp files? in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, class, user-interface

I have problem with my small app in Qt framework C++

I have a first window which there's two buttons where you can choose to play music or video. The music button will close the "choose window" and should open "music window" and similarly for video button.

I don't know how to do this... I know a way which I've leant and used but this method I'm going to explain how it doesn't fit to my current issue.

I've created a pointer of that window class in header of choose window and when the music button is clicked, I new the pointer and `musicWindow->show();` and `hide();` the choose window, this is good but there is a problem:

the new opened music window doesn't have any taskbar icon/thumbnail and when Its minimized there's no way to have that opened again(except wtih alt-tab)

and dont find a way to open it like a complete new window, I just can open all of them at once by using `choosWindow.show();` / `musicWindow.show();` /... .

I know there must be a way, but I dont even know what topics to search for to get further...

```
FirstWindow.cpp:
void FirstWindow::on_musicChoose_clicked()
{
    //send a signal from here
}

void FirstWindow::on_videoChoose_clicked()
{
    //send a signal from here
}

main.cpp:
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    FirstWindow w;

    if(//what condition?)
    {
        MusicWindow mw;
        mw.show();
    }
    if(//what condition?)
    {
        VideoWindow vw;
        vw.show();
    }
    

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing code you should create a [MRE] and post that ***actual code***.

Comment: use signal slot. When music button is clicked, emit a signal which you connect to a slot that does what you want

Comment: [might be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792351/qt-force-child-window-to-have-its-own-task-bar-entry)

Comment: @bolov i added some code but im sure this doesnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in Qt Forum:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/68602/child-window-in-taskbar/3

@Radek(Qt Forum): Try passing 0 (zero) as parent when you create them.

```
FirstWindow.cpp:
void FirstWindow::on_musicChoose_clicked()
{
    this->hide();
    mw = new MusicWindow(0); // passing nullptr as parent
    mw.show();
}

void FirstWindow::on_videoChoose_clicked()
{
    this->hide();
    vw = new VideoWindow(0); // passing nullptr as parent
    vw.show();
}

main.cpp:
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    FirstDialog w;
    w.exec();
    

    return a.exec();
}
```